# Shortcut Ctrl+Shift+d does not work anymore

Tags: keyboard

M12.1, Win10: all of a sudden <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> does not work anymore to divide a cell: nothing happens, except a warning beep. Right-click Divide Cell works normally. MenuSetup.tr contains MenuItem["Di&vide Cell", "CellSplit", MenuKey["D", Modifiers->{"Control", "Shift"}]], and has not changed. Ctrl+Shift+m works normally.
In spite of the beep, "Why the Beep?" keeps answering "The Wolfram System hasn't beeped yet." So I suspect it is Win10, but no other application is running.
How to repair this shortcut?

Comment: Works fine for me, 12.1 on Windows 10...

Comment: All my ctrl-shift keyboard shortcuts seem to have broken as of the last version update (12.1), and I'm on MacOS. I used to rely on ctrl-shift-6 for superscript, ctrl-shift-2 for square root, etc. because I've got ctrl-(number) as my hot-key for switching OS desktop spaces.

Comment: After exactly one year (!), I found the culprit: Dell Display Manager apparently takes priority with the same keyboard shortcut. Uninstalling DDM resolved the problem.